# Incrementing an IP range based on last octet | PHP

Tags: php, arrays, ip, increment

I have two variables, `$newIpStart` and `$newIpEnd`.

Any idea how I can increment the last octet, from the `$newIpStart` to `$newIpEnd` and store it in array f.e.?

---

To be more clear take a look at the example.

```
$newIpStart = '192.168.1.1'; //string
$newIpEnd = '192.168.1.150'; //string
```

I would like to get all IP's between 192.168.1.**1** and 192.168.1.**150** (including start IP and end IP). 
Note, that in the example `192.168.1` (first three octets are static - they don't change), only the last one needs to be incremented.

So in between, I should get IP's like :

```
`192.168.1.1` 
`192.168.1.2` 
`192.168.1.3` 
.. n .. 
`192.168.1.150`
```

After I get all those IP's I would store it in array, so I can loop it, and do some operation on each IP.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using explode version :

```
$newIpStart = '192.168.1.1';
$newIpEnd = '192.168.1.150';
$arrayIpStart = explode('.', $newIpStart);
$arrayIpEnd = explode('.', $newIpEnd);
$count = end($arrayIpEnd) - end($arrayIpStart);
$arrayIpResult = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    $arrayIpStart[3] = $i;
    $arrayIpResult []= implode('.', $arrayIpStart);
}

return $arrayIpResult;
```

It shoud works, not the best way I think.

Comment: Yea, something like that, but please note that I need `$count` to be calculated within the script in order to increment. So basicaly, it would be great if I could subtract, like `192.168.1.150 - 192.168.1.1` = `149` and get the count, but it isn't possible. :)

Comment: Just do : `$count = $arrayIpStart[3] - $arrayIpEnd[3];`. Look my answer edited.

Comment: Perfect, just tested. :) Thanks everyone!

Comment: I've updated your `for` loop. With the current approach I get desired results. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a while loop:

```
$base = '192.168.1.'; 
$ips = array(); 
$i = 1;

while($i < 150){
    $ips[] = $base.$i;  
    $i++; 
}

var_dump($ips);
```

If you are unsure of the end of the range, you can use a string function to get the last octet and use that in your loop.